# Open CSV file as CSV::Table form URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have written methods that manipulates `CSV::Table` objects for a rails application. It reads files using `CSV.read(file_path)` method. However, the application logic has changed, and it's not reading from a local file anymore, but from a URL.

I can load the CSV file using `open-uri` gem `open` method; however it creates a `StringIO` object, that can be parsed into an array of rows,  but I wasn't able to convert it into a `CSV::Table` object.

How can I read a CSV file from URL and convert it into a `CSV::Table` object - so as I preserve the existing methods?

I'm thinking of overwriting the existing `CSV.open` method that is used by `CSV.read` method, but I'm not sure how safe is to do that. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function get file content using `open-uri`  and convert it to a `CSV::Table` object:

```
require 'csv'
require 'open-uri'

def read_url
  # Get StringIO from URL using open-uri
  stringio = open(file_url)

  # Create a new CSV object from StringIO
  csvobj = CSV.new(stringio)

  # Create an array of rows from CSV object
  array_of_rows = csvobj.read

  # Separate header from values
  header = array_of_rows[0]
  aux = array_of_rows.length - 1
  values = array_of_rows[1..aux]

  # Create array of CSV::Row objects
  values_row = values.map { |row| CSV::Row.new(header, row) }

  # Create a CSV::Table object from array of CSV::Row
  CSV::Table.new(values_row)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`CSV.new(stringio)` should do the trick (see the [doc](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new) for details)

edit: untested. If that doesn't work, try [CSV.generate](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-generate)

Comment: Indeed, it creates a `CSV` object from the `StringIO` object. However, it's not a `CSV::Table` object, which have its own methods, e.g., `by_col`, `by_row`, etc.

Comment: `CSV.generate` is used to create CSV files. Your suggestion is to use that method to create a temporary file, and load it through the command I was initially using (`CSV.read`)? That might work, but seems to be overwhelming. I alwready have a `StringIO` with CSV contents; I need to find a way to convert it to a `CSV::Table` object.

Comment: [CSV::Table.new](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Table.html#method-c-new) receives a `CSV::Row` object. I tried converting my `StringIO` to a `CSV::Row`, but when I use it as argument to `CSV::Table.new` it says that (Object doesn't support #inspect).